# What is a simple build and deploy process using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to understand what a good practice is for what I would assume is a pretty common scenario of building and deploying a kubernetes deployment using kubectl.

Scenario:

- I want to build a project and deploy it to my cluster.
- I’ve got a yaml file with my deployment (and related things), and some src code with a Dockerfile.
- I want to avoid using **:latest** in the image tag as per [Best Practice recommendation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images) and instead use a unique tag for that image.
- I have easy access to a unique identifier, either coming from CI or git sha that is available as an environment variable at time of building.

So that seems pretty simple:

```
docker build -t my-registry/my-app:${BUILD_NUMBER} .
docker push my-registry/my-app:${BUILD_NUMBER}
kubectl apply -f kube.yaml
```

Except that there is no native way to tell kubectl what image name to use.

I understand that [kubectl does not support environment variable template substitution](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787#issuecomment-369645645), but I've never seen just the usecase of image tags being mentioned explicitly.

I can use [sed replacement](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787#issuecomment-369397528) but that seems to go against the spirit of 'no variable template support', and I barely understand what sed does when I write it, so I pitty the next developer who has to read my commands.

I feel like for such a basic scenario "I want to build and deploy to my cluster" there might be a simpler solution that doesn’t feel like it’s fighting kubectl.

Skaffold does a great job of assigning a tag and digest for each built image, but it would be nice to have a simple process to start with before bringing in more high level tooling.

- Besides "Use Skaffold" or "Use Helm" what should I do to have a simple build + deploy process?
- Is templating yaml files okay, either with sed, mo, or other replacement tools?
- Are there any example projects that have a simple build and deploy pipeline using just kubectl and maybe kustomize?

**kube.yaml** (Note the lack of version on the image name)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: example
  name: my-app
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 2
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-app
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: "my-registry/my-app"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 300m
              memory: 600m
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100m
```

Answer (score 1):

Is [`kubectl set image <deployment> <image>`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) an option? It does what you are looking for, but it won't be reflected in your local copy of `kube.yaml`, so you would need to specify a dummy image for "my-registry/my-app" in `kube.yaml` to not confuse other developers that they have to change that value each time they want to re-deploy.

Comment: `kubectl set image` seems ideal for making the minimum change to the deployment for a release, but as you've mentioned it's not represented in the yaml, resulting in the next `kubectl apply` blowing away the set image.
I think that would be an unfortunate compromise. Though maybe if there was a way to batch kubectl commands you could run them both as an atomic action during deployment? I don't think there is but that might be cool.

Comment: So you want `kubectl` to support env variable template substition, but as you said that ain't happening, so you need a different tool. I think bash `kubectl apply -f kube.yaml && kubectl set image` is the simplest and the most readable. I wouldn't use `sed` , as you said. And if you want to go nuts, try out `terraform`. It also works by `terraform apply` (and is built to be able to handle these kind of dependencies), and I feel if you are looking for a single `apply` command that does it all, you could try it out.

Answer (score 0):

for simple cases you can use [kubectl run](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run). for example:

`kubectl run my-app --image=my-registry/my-app:${BUILD_NUMBER} --port=3000 --replicas=1 --env VAR=value --expose --limits 'cpu=300m,memory=600Mi'`

in theory it's a deprecated command, but it's been deprecated for 2 years now and it's still there ;] anyway, if you feel unsafe about it, the message gives a hint how you can waste a day or 2 to make it in a non-deprecated way ;]